# TOKENIZE keyword query Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a newbie in Pig. The dataset is

```
-1,xyz,bio
-2,abcd,physics
```

I ran following queries ,

```
z1 = load 'demo.txt' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);

z2 = foreach z1 generate TOKENIZE(z1.name,','); --- gives error "scalar has more than one row in o/p"

z2 = foreach z1 generate TOKENIZE(name,','); -- ran fine
```

describe z1:

```
z1: {name:chararray}
```

From what i read is dot operator is used to dereference tuple or bag . here z1 is my tuple and i am trying to get field by dereferencing. so z1.name should be equal to name. Please help me to understand where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `z1` is relation with name as column. To identify/reference column of relation you need to use `::` .

Correct script would be

```
z1 = load 'demo.txt' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);
z2 = foreach z1 generate TOKENIZE(z1::name,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data has three fields.

```
id,name,subject
```

Pig, by default,loads the file with tab delimited. You need to define the delimiter as well.

Either define the schema in load statement or use the index $0, $1...

```
z1 = LOAD 'demo.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id: int, name:chararray, subject : chararray);
z2 = FOREACH z1 GENERATE z1.name
```

In this way, you can use **z1.id, z1.name,z1.subject** to print the values.